# Group an array by its key name. [Keyname is depends on the input by user]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

this is my code to produce array

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct SubCode ORDER BY SubCode SEPARATOR ' ')as           
SubCode,GROUP_CONCAT(grade ORDER BY SubCode SEPARATOR ' ')as grade FROM VMESubjectGrade      
where ProgCode='$a' and Sessi='$b' and Intake='$c' GROUP BY matricNo";

$cols = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(distinct SubCode ORDER BY SubCode SEPARATOR ' ')as   
SubCode,sub_id FROM VMESubjectGrade where ProgCode='$a' and Sessi='$b' and 
Intake='$c' order by SubCode" ;


$result = mysql_query($cols); 


$gradee = mysql_query($query);


while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{  $pixx =explode(" ", $row1['SubCode']);

} 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($gradee))

{
$pieces =explode(" ", $row['SubCode']);
$comps = array_intersect($pixx, $pieces);
$pi =explode(" ", $row['grade']);
$conbi = array_combine ($comps ,$pi );

//print_r($conbi);

echo array2table($conbi);
 }
`array2table` is a function that produce table for any array
```

this is my array

```
conbi = 

Array ( [MMB617] => I )

Array ( [MBP633] => B+ [MMB617] => C- [MQM613] => A- )

Array ( [MCT654] => A- [MMB617] => B- [MTH651] => B+ )

Array ( [MPP799] => A- ) 

Array ( [MMB617] => I [MMD634] => I [MQM613] => I ) 

Array ( [MBP633] => A- [MVF632] => A ) Array ( [MPP799] => B ) 

Array ( [MMB617] => I [MQM613] => I )
```

when i output by table it look like this

```
MMB617
I
MBP633         MMB617           MQM613
B+              C-                  A-
MCT654         MMB617           MTH651
A-               B-                 B+
MPP799
A-
MMB617         MMD634            MQM613
 I               I                I
MBP633         MVF632
 A-              A
MPP799
 B
MMB617         MQM613
 I               I
```

I want my array to be group by subject so that all subject will be the title and my table look like this

```
MBP633  MCT654  MMB617  MMD634  MPP799  MQM613  MTH651  MVF632
                    I
B+                  C-                       A-
            A-      B-                             B+
                            A-
                    I       I                I
A-                                                        A
                                    B
                    I                        I
```

Comment: You may want to clean your post, the code and the problem are hardly readable and the context is not properly defined.

Comment: done cleaning my fren

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and so is your code. Try this

```
$ordered = array()
foreach ($conbi as $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $key=>$value){
       if(!array_key_exists($key, $ordered){$ordered[$key] = array();}
       array_push($ordered[$key], $value);
    }
}

print_r($ordered);
```

It's better for you to make clear questions in order to get good or any answer. Look around to see good examples.

Comment: It's not clear for me then how your array looks like.

Comment: when i print_r $combi it looks like this exactly Array ( [MMB617] => I ) Array ( [MBP633] => B+ [MMB617] => C- [MQM613] => A- ) Array ( [MCT654] => A- [MMB617] => B- [MTH651] => B+ ) Array ( [MPP799] => A- ) Array ( [MMB617] => I [MMD634] => I [MQM613] => I ) Array ( [MBP633] => A- [MVF632] => A ) Array ( [MPP799] => B ) Array ( [MMB617] => I [MQM613] => I )

Comment: You should embedded your `print_r` in html `<pre></pre>` bracket for easier reading